# MacBook Pro black screen - or reset password

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

My MacBook Pro fails to start.
I hear the "ding" sound, the keyboard lights up, but the screen stays black.

After a couple of minutes, I hear the fans growing louder, until after a few minutes, the computer stops.

I tried a few times, also closing the lid, plugging to a TV, options key, etc. Nothing.

Except, once in a while, it *seems* to start correctly, the screen turns on, and then it tells me I have forgotten my password and offers to reset it.

There is no option to say "NO I haven't forgotten".

When I play along and reset my password, at the end of the process it says my password was successfully reset (including something about FireVault), then it requires me to restart the computer to complete.

Of course, once I restart, I'm back to square one with the black screen. I've managed to reproduce the reset screen 3 times so far - without really coming up with a rule as to when it happens. The rest of the time, just black screen.

It's a MacBook Pro 15" from 2011 (I think), running Yosemite.

Comment: Once it is running (on rare occasion) copy and paste here your console log some 50 lines please.

Comment: How can I possibly copy or paste anything? Like I said, the only times it worked was to show the reset password screen. No safari or finder or terminal or anything....

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you information. So it does not start at all. How about Safe mode (shift), or cmd-r, or Apple Hardware test (D)

Comment: Same problem here on a 17" MacBook Pro running Yosemite.

Answer (score 9):

This happened to me too with my macbook pro 15 (mid 2012) running yosemite. What I did is took a flashlight and see if there was an image still on the screen. What I found out is that I was able to see the log in screen but it was all dark. After logging in all was back to normal.

Eventually if that doesn't work you can reset the pram of your computer. Follow this link http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht3964 .

Comment: Thanks Norman for your answer, resetting the pram didn't work for me and I did not know what you meant with flashlight (i tried to "side light" it with the flashlight from my iphone but that didn't work) But when I tried to light my screen from the back I noticed I could shine through the apple logo on the back of the screen and it showed my the login UI (not visible without flashlight). This problem seems to be that the backlight (?) of the screen is not turned on in this situation.

Comment: I can't believe that shining my phone's flashlight in through the Apple logo actually worked. I'm normally a Windows man myself, but I truly am through the Mac looking glass now.

Comment: This worked for me as well on my mic-2012 MacBook Pro. Thanks!

Comment: Unbelievable, but it worked! Thanks